# Ubunt 13.04 Icons disappeared

Tags: icons

My Bars on top and at left disappeared. I can now only right click and choose - change desktop background - Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> bring terminal out. Problem is I know **nothing** about it. There is now only my wall paper on the screen.

Comment: No still the same problem. It seems ill have to loose all software and re-install.

Answer (score 1):

down vote
I found this answer on the net and it work for me

In 13.04, unity  use the following:

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/ 
unity --reset-icons &disown